# Django. If boolean true = redirect

Tags: django

I set up a redirect for objects in the directory. If there is a mark in the checkbox, it means a redirect to the category. But now I have all the objects redirected to a category. What am I doing wrong?

In my **models.py**

```
is_redirect = models.BooleanField('Redirect', default=False)
```

In my **views.py**

```
def kv(request, kv_id):
    kv = get_object_or_404(Objects, pk=kv_id)
    response = redirect('/category/')
    response.status_code = 301
    context = {
        'kv': kv
    }
    if Objects.objects.all().filter(is_redirect=True):
        return response
    else:
        return render(request, 'listings/product-templates/listing-kv.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You here perform a redirect if *at least* one such `Objects` exist. You should work on the `kv` part itself:

```
def kv(request, kv_id):
    kv_obj = get_object_or_404(Objects, pk=kv_id)
    if kv_obj.is_redirect:
        return redirect('/category/', permanent=True)
    else:
        context = {
            'kv': kv_obj
        }
        return render(request, 'listings/product-templates/listing-kv.html', context)
```

Note that you can use `permanent=True`, which is probably more self-explaining and declarative.